# primeng p-table checkbox and filter

Tags: html, angular, frontend, primeng, primeng-datatable

[image: please i dont know how to fix this. The table filter is not aligning with the table header]

Hello everyone! i am using p-table, p-headercheckbox, p-tableCheckbox and additional filter for each column. The problem is that filters are not aligning with headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include an empty `<th></th>` before the rest of the filters to take the place of the checkbox column.

```html
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
    ...
  </th>
</tr>
```